# Unable to show the data on Jtable

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to make a Client Server Architecture in which the client sends his Hardware level specification to the server. But I am not able to show the data on GUI. The client information are received at server side properly.

**Server Code**

```
public class MyServer extends JFrame {
public void Show() throws IOException
{
    ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(6666);
    int count=0;
        while(true)
        {
            Socket s=null;
             try{ 
            s=ss.accept();
            SocketThread socketThread=new SocketThread(s,count);
            socketThread.start();

            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                s.close();
            System.out.println(e);
            }
            finally {
                count++;                
            }
        }
}
}
class SocketThread extends Thread
{
      // variables decleration

      public SocketThread(Socket csocket,int count) {
      this.csocket = csocket;
      this.count=count;
      }
      public void run(){
        try { 
            DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(csocket.getInputStream());
            // Assigning the value to the variables
            csocket.close();
            dis.close();
            ShowTable st=new ShowTable();
            st.showdata(count,host, ip, os_name, os_arch, os_version, pro_detail, Mac_add, disk_size, max_memory);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            System.out.println("Server Problem");
            System.out.println(e);
            }
      }
}
```

**GUI Code to Show the Client info**

```
public class ShowTable extends JFrame{
    JFrame f=new JFrame();
    JTable jt=new JTable(new DefaultTableModel());
    DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)jt.getModel();
    public void showdata(int count,String host,String ip,String os_name,String os_arch,
    String os_version,String pro_detail,String Mac_add,float disk_size,float max_memory){        

    Object data[]={host,ip,os_name,os_arch,os_version,pro_detail,Mac_add,disk_size,max_memory};     
    if (count == 0)
    {       
        model.addColumn("HOSTNAME");
        model.addColumn("IP ADDRESS");
        model.addColumn("OS NAME");
        model.addColumn("OS ARCHITECTURE");
        model.addColumn("OS VERSION");
        model.addColumn("PROCESSOR DETAIL");
        model.addColumn("MAC ADDRESS");
        model.addColumn("HARD DISK");
        model.addColumn("RAM SIZE");
        model.addRow(data);  
    }
    else
    {
        model.addRow(data);
    }
    jt.setBounds(30,40,200,300);          
    jt.setFocusable(false);
    jt.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
    JScrollPane sp=new JScrollPane(jt);    
    f.add(sp);          
    f.setSize(1300,100);   
    f.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(){
         JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
         JTable jTable1;
    }
}
```

But this Jframe code showing a blank frame So can anyone please help me where I am doing wrong because it is showing the output on console.

Comment: Based on the code, the UI will only be displayed on the server - is this your intention?

Comment: Yes, the UI will only displayed on server machine.

Comment: Actually, whenever new client send his detail. This will be added to the table using addRow() method.

Comment: `System.getenv("processor_identifier")` is return `null` on my system, might want to check into that

Comment: Once I get rid of `System.getenv("processor_identifier")`, it works fine for me

Comment: System.getenv("processor_identifier") is showing this "Intel64 Family 6 Model 78 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel" on my system

Comment: Well, it was giving me a `NullPointerException`. Once I removed it, the code ran and displayed the UI.  Check that no other error are been generated. Remove all unnecessary `main` methods, because that was confusing

Comment: It working thanks. But it still creating new frame each time is their any way to add that in one Jtable.

Comment: Well, create a single instance of the frame when the `MyServer` class is created. Use this single instance to add new rows. Remember, Swing is not thread safe, so you will need to take that into consideration

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you Sir, Can you please provide me the code if possible as i am not able to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thank you Sir, Can you please provide me the code if possible as i am not able to do this

The basic idea is, you only want one instance of the `JFrame` to ever exist, all instances of your `SocketThread` should then reference this single instance.

While there are a number of ways you might achieve this, using a singleton pattern is probably one of the simplest

## `ShowTable`

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public enum ShowTable  {

    INSTANCE;

    private JFrame f = new JFrame();
    private JTable jt = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel());
    private DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jt.getModel();

    private ShowTable() {
        jt.setBounds(30, 40, 200, 300);
        jt.setFocusable(false);
        jt.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(jt);
        f.add(sp);
        f.setSize(1300, 100);
    }

    public void showdata(int count, String host, String ip, String os_name, String os_arch,
            String os_version, String pro_detail, String Mac_add, float disk_size, float max_memory) {
        //System.out.println("Row  :"+count);
        Object data[] = {host, ip, os_name, os_arch, os_version, pro_detail, Mac_add, disk_size, max_memory};
        if (count == 0) {
            model.addColumn("HOSTNAME");
            model.addColumn("IP ADDRESS");
            model.addColumn("OS NAME");
            model.addColumn("OS ARCHITECTURE");
            model.addColumn("OS VERSION");
            model.addColumn("PROCESSOR DETAIL");
            model.addColumn("MAC ADDRESS");
            model.addColumn("HARD DISK");
            model.addColumn("RAM SIZE");
            model.addRow(data);
        } else {
            model.addRow(data);
        }
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

## `MyServer` (and `SocketThread`)

import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;

```
public class MyServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new MyServer().Show();
    }

    public void Show() throws IOException {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(6666);
        int count = 0;
        while (true) {
            Socket s = null;
            try {
                s = ss.accept();
                SocketThread socketThread = new SocketThread(s, count);
                socketThread.start();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                s.close();
                System.out.println(e);
            } finally {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    class SocketThread extends Thread {

        Socket csocket;
        String ip = null;
        String host = null;
        String os_name = null;
        String os_arch = null;
        String os_version = null;
        String pro_detail = null;
        String Mac_add = null;
        float disk_size = 0;
        float max_memory = 0;
        int count;

        public SocketThread(Socket csocket, int count) {
            this.csocket = csocket;
            this.count = count;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(csocket.getInputStream());
                host = (String) dis.readUTF();
                ip = (String) dis.readUTF();
                os_name = (String) dis.readUTF();
                os_arch = (String) dis.readUTF();
                os_version = (String) dis.readUTF();
//                pro_detail = (String) dis.readUTF();
                Mac_add = (String) dis.readUTF();
                disk_size = (long) (dis.readLong() / (1000000000));
                max_memory = (long) (dis.readLong() / (1000000000));
                csocket.close();
                dis.close();
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ShowTable.INSTANCE.showdata(count, host, ip, os_name, os_arch, os_version, pro_detail, Mac_add, disk_size, max_memory);
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Server Problem");
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## `MyClient`

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.NetworkInterface;
    import java.net.Socket;

```
public class MyClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        InetAddress ip;
        try {
            long diskSize = new File("C:").getTotalSpace() + new File("D:").getTotalSpace() + new File("E:").getTotalSpace();
            long memorySize = ((com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean()).getTotalPhysicalMemorySize();
            ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 6666);
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            dout.writeUTF(ip.getHostName());
            dout.writeUTF(ip.getHostAddress());
            dout.writeUTF(System.getProperty("os.name"));
            dout.writeUTF(System.getProperty("os.arch"));
            dout.writeUTF(System.getProperty("os.version"));
//            dout.writeUTF(System.getenv("processor_identifier"));
            NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();
            for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
                sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
            }
            dout.writeUTF(sb.toString());
            dout.writeLong(diskSize);
            dout.writeLong(memorySize);
            dout.flush();
            dout.close();
            s.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Client");
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I need to make any changes in ShowTable class because this code is also making a new frame for each client.

Comment: @ChandrapalSinghJhala `showData` doesn't make a new frame, it only makes one